# How to send email when values in a certain cell change

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet to analyze fluctuations. I want the software to send an email when the cell increases by 10% from it's previous value. I read another answer on here from a few years ago that says you can get google sheets to do that when you want changes to a certain number (i.e. if the value goes over 2), but I was wondering if it could be done for % changes. i.e. if a cell that has 114.25 in it right now increases to 125.678 or more, I would like an email.

Any help would be greatly appreciated to get it to alert me when a 10% change in values occurs. Thanks!

Here is some that I've tried based on code I found online... I took a coding course in college, but not for software, only for websites...

```
    function getValue() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Perc");
      var value = sheet.getRange("B3").getValue();
      var title = sheet.getRange("B1").getValue();
      if(value >= "1") sendEmail(value, title)
    };


    function sendEmail(value, title){
      var recipient="someemail@gmail.com";
      var subject=title + "Percent Change";
      var body=title + " percent changed by " + value + "%";
      MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
    };
```

I just dont know how to make it for a change in percentage instead of greater than or equal to 1...

Comment: What have you tried so far? This isn't the right place to ask if you want code built to your requirement.

Comment: The "%" sign is a red-herring - that's just formatting. When you `getValues`, the real numbers are  1.1424 and 1.25678 so compare than accordingly.

Comment: You want onEdit(e) [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) which will return the "oldValue" and the new "value"; just do the maths and send the email (or not) depending on the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

> If your value in the sheet get auto-updated - you will always see only
>   the new value and will not be able to compare it to the old one.

### I suggest that you implement a function that copies the actual value multiplied by the desired percentage factor to a secondary sheet every time you run your script.

**Here an idea:**

```
    function getValue() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Perc");
      var value = sheet.getRange("B3").getValue();
      var title = sheet.getRange("B1").getValue();
      //check if copySheet exists already, otherwise insert it
       if (!ss.getSheetByName("copySheet")) {
        ss.insertSheet("copySheet");
       } 
      copySheet=ss.getSheetByName("copySheet"); 
      var percentage=110;
      var copiedCell=copySheet.getRange("B3");
      var oldValue=copiedCell.getValue();
      // rounding necessary due to JS characteristic handling of floating point values
      var change=(Math.round(value/oldValue*100));
      if(change >= percentage) {
        sendEmail(value, title, change)
      }
      copiedCell.setValue(value);
    };

    function sendEmail(value, title, change){
      var recipient="someemail@gmail.com";
      var subject=title + "Percent Change";
      var body=value + " changed by " + change + " percent";
      MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
    };
```